# problema con Double, int

Tags: java, double

Al código para sumar todos los números almacenados, me sale el error

> "cannot convert from double to int" ***ac=ac+v[i];***.

```
package actividad02;
import java.io.*;
public class ejercicio03 
{

// public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

    InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
    double[] v=new double[5];
    int op;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {

    do {
    System.out.print("dime cinco valores decimales: ");
    v [i]=Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
       }while ((v[i]<0)|| (v[i] >100));


    }
    System.out.println("Introduzca la operación a realizar del siguiente menú de opciones: ");
    System.out.println("1.-Modificar el valor almacenado en una posición: ");
    System.out.println("2.-Mostrar el resultado de sumar todos los números: ");
    System.out.println("3.-Mostrar el número más alto y más bajo: ");
    System.out.println("4.-Situar el número más alto en la 1a posición y el más bajo en la última: ");
    System.out.println("0.-Finalizar");
    op=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());


    switch (op)
    {
    case 1:
        int [] v1;
        int N;
        System.out.print("dime un número del 0 al 100 ");
        N=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        v1=new int[N];
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
        System.out.print("está en la "+(N)+"ª posición");
        v1[i]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }       
        break;

    case 2:

        double ac;  
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {

            ***ac=ac+v[i];***

        }   
        System.out.println("suma: "+ac);




        break;







    }   
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, en el `case` 2 en tu `switch`, estás tratando de llamar a `N`, que es una variable que se creo y está inicializada en el `case` 1:

```java
case 2:
        double ac;  
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){...}
```

Por lo mismo esa variable no se va a encontrar cuando se llame al `case` 2, como en la opción 2, dice que si se selecciona devolverá el resultado de la suma de todos los valores que se encuentren dentro del `Array` `v1`, entonces en lugar de llamar a `N` se debería de llamar a la cantidad total de datos que tiene `v1`, con el método `length`:

```java
case 2:
        double ac;  
        ac = 0; //ac inicializada
        for(int i = 0 ; i < v.length ; i++)
        {
            ac = ac + v[i];
        }   
        System.out.println("suma: "+ac);
```

Además para poder realizar el contador de manera correcta, se debe de inicializar en 0, para poder agregar valores.

### Resultado

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola si es que esta respuesta ha resuelto tu duda, no olvides marcarla como aceptada, en el símbolo check (✔) al costado izquierdo de la pregunta :)